# What is top_level.txt and when is it created?

Tags: python, site-packages

## Background

From [The Internal Structure of Python Eggs](https://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/doc/formats.txt) (hosted by python.org), I learned that there's a file called `top_level.txt` that is installed alongside Python eggs that says what top-level modules or packages are installed.

[packaging.python.org](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/recording-installed-packages/) does not list `top_level.txt` as a file that is to be created and added to `dist-info`. However when I manually inspect dependencies inside of `site-packages`, I haven't run across a case yet where that file *doesn't* exist.

## Question

In short, where and when is this file created?

I've observed that it always seems to exist when I install a package (either in `.egg-info` or `.dist-info`), but is this a pattern I can expect to generally be the case?

Answer (score 2):

this file is not always present but is added by `setuptools` during the `egg-info` phase

https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/0d4d5565b1d9557f0b434adc87a0415abd2a5cc9/setuptools/command/egg_info.py#L707-L714

```
def write_toplevel_names(cmd, basename, filename):
    pkgs = dict.fromkeys(
        [
            k.split('.', 1)[0]
            for k in cmd.distribution.iter_distribution_names()
        ]
    )
    cmd.write_file("top-level names", filename, '\n'.join(sorted(pkgs)) + '\n')
```

here's an example of a wheel which does not contain one: https://pypi.org/project/distlib/0.3.4/

(the actual wheel file from pypi)

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/a3/8ee4f54d5f12e16eeeda6b7df3dfdbda24e6cc572c86ff959a4ce110391b/distlib-0.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl